# Google Cloud won't SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform

Out of the blue, my Google Cloud instance ran out of space, causing me to not be able to SSH in and fix, cannot resize the disk due to resizefs.

I've nearly tried everything:

Serial console (using startup script to create username and password), doesn't work since startup scripts won't run on the bad drive.

Putting it on a separate instance and having it as an additional drive, still causes same issues and cannot SSH even on then.

Changing the size of the disk on gcloud cmd line, didn't do anything

Works on a new box without the bad drive, cannot be the instance settings.

How am I supposed to free space when I cannot access the drive at all? I only have Cloud Storage free plan so I cannot export the image and manually free space on it. Stuck on this for a few days, all Google results are purple, none have worked. If anyone has any good ideas that I haven't already tried, please suggest them.